# Do multiple machines declared in a Vagrantfile have to be based on the same base box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

From the documentation you can address the need to have multiple environments running to reproduce your production (like one db machine, one web machine etc.):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "apache"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "mysql"
  end
end
```

This is well explained but I also understand they will be all based on the same box: e.g. ubuntu-1404 for instance.

What happens if you need the db box to be on oracle linux, the web box on ubuntu for instance?
Appart from creating two directories with two Vagrantfile I don't see any other option.

Has anyone ever done that and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the boxes can definitely be different. The example you showed (from the [Multi-Machine doc page](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html) is a big confusing because it's not clear what "apache" and "mysql" are referring to.

You can set `*.vm.box` to actual box names. For example, finding a couple of boxes from the [Vagrant cloud](https://vagrantcloud.com/discover/featured) might change your example Vagrantfile to:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "box-cutter/oel65"
  end
end
```

Comment: Tks @BrianC I was indeed confused. The "apache" I took as a typology in the vagrant doc is actually a vagrant box name.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are free to overwrite *every* setting - which you have already done. Didn't you tested it?